How to debug a testify golang code which is deployed in k8s cluster as job using vscode?
I am trying to debug golang test code which is deployed as job in local k8s cluster.
I have installed cloud code extension.
In my dockerfile I have installed dlv.
dockerfile is as below
FROM myorg.com/docker_proxy/library/golang:1.20-alpine3.17 as base


# ENV GOTRACEBACK=all

ARG USER=default

RUN go version

# install build tools
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add -U --no-cache \
    curl \
    git  \
    make \
    bash \
    ;

# add new user
RUN addgroup -g 1000 ${USER} \
    && adduser -h /build -D -u 1000 -G ${USER} ${USER} \
    ;

USER ${USER}

RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

# RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go get -ldflags "-s -w -extldflags '-static'" github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
WORKDIR /build

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM base as build


ARG USER=default
COPY --chown=${USER}:${USER} . ./

# add personal token
ARG VERSION=0.0.0
ARG TOKEN="<git token>"

# docker command runs in a sandbox env. we will need to pass the git proxy in the
# dockerfile so that it can be picked up in the sandbox
RUN set -eux; \
    if [[ ! -z "$TOKEN" ]]; then \
    git config --global url."https://x-oauth-basic:${TOKEN}@github.myorg.com/".insteadof https://github.myorg.com/; \
    fi; \
    go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.myorg.com"; \
    make test-build VERSION=${VERSION};

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Runtime image
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM myorg.com/docker_proxy/library/golang:1.20-alpine3.17  as runtime

ARG USER=default
ENV HOME /home/${USER}

# add new user
RUN addgroup -g 1000 ${USER} \
    && adduser -D -u 1000 -G ${USER} ${USER} \
    ;

USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=build /build/dist/dci-setup-tests ./dci-setup-tests
COPY --from=build /build/tests/specs ./specs
COPY --from=build /go/bin/dlv ./dlv
ENTRYPOINT [ "/dlv" ,"debug", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "/dci-setup-tests"]

Below is my launch.json of vscode
{
            "name": "Kubernetes: Run/Debug",
            "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
            "request": "launch",
            "skaffoldConfig": "${workspaceFolder}/dci-setup/dci-setup-tests/skaffold.yaml",
            "watch": true,
            "cleanUp": true,
            "portForward": true,
            "imageRegistry": "docker.artifactory.myorg.com",
            "debug": [
                {
                    "image": "docker.artifactory.myorg.com/dcs-docker/testuser/dci/dci-setup-tests",
                    "containerName": "dci-setup-tests",
                    "sourceFileMap": {
                        "${workspaceFolder}/dci-setup/dci-setup-tests/tests/functional/nwautov2.go": "/build/tests/functional/nwautov2.go"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

When i click debug App from vscode cloud code extension, it build docker image ,push image to artifcatory and executed the job but debugger is not hit.
Is it possible to debug golang testify test code?
Can some one help me what i am missing?

Hi Samselvaprabu, you are running dlv manually but are using launch instead of attach.  Can you try "request":"attach" with "debugPort": 40000 in your launch config?
